# C# Convert Action<Car> to Action<List<Car>

Tags: c#, type-conversion, action

I have a method which takes in an argument of `Action<List<Car>`  which is invoked on a list in that method. (method 2)

In another method which calls aforementioned method I have an `Action<Car>` as input argument.

When the invoke in method 2 happens I want my `Action<Car>` from method 1 to be invoked.

I have no clue how to convert `Action<Car>` to `Action<List<Car>` Without invoking stuff already in the method which has the action on the Car only.

Example (http://rextester.com/STWWVO99830):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var car = ExpectCar(model =>
        {
            foreach (var type in model.Types)
            {
                type.Name = "SuperStarShineType";
            }
        });
    }



    public static Car ExpectCar(Action<Car> preProcessor)
    {
        var car = new Car();
        preProcessor.Invoke(car);

        var carList = new List<Car> { car };
        var carActionList = new Action<List<Car>>(list => list = carList);

        return ExpectCars(carActionList).Single();
    }


    public static List<Car> ExpectCars(Action<List<Car>> preProcessor)
    {
        var carList = new List<Car> {
            new Car {
                Types = new List<Type> {
                    new Type {Name = "SuperCar"}
                }
            }
        };

        preProcessor.Invoke(carList);

        return carList;
    }

}
class Car
{
    public List<Type> Types { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It gives me a null reference exception because the types are empty because I invoked to early. The invoke needs to happen only in the second method.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Can you use something like http://rextester.com/runcode to provide a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: http://rextester.com/STWWVO99830 here you go, thanks for the sugestion

Comment: Yeah the null reference stems from model.Types being empty my question is how to convert action<car> to action<list<car>> without invoking anything? If it did not show any errors I would not post here with this issue :(. I know the code is wrong but its as close as I can get to what I want.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `Action<Car>` and `Action<List<Car>>` are 2 different things

Comment: I missed that the problem was the NRE. Anyway its still totally unclear what you're *actually trying to achieve*. It looks like you should just be passing `List<Car>` to `ExpectCars` not the `Action<List<Car>>` that youre trying to now.

Comment: Your problem stems from this line `var carActionList = new Action<List<Car>>(list => list = carList);` you cant assign back to `list` like that

Comment: my aim is: call one of those methods in a test and in one method edit a list and in one other method edit only one object (goal is to reduce extra code which obfuscates the real thing being tested), maybe there is my next mistake but currently it wont go further then the nonexistant list being iterated over

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly?